# Combining Angularjs and CodeIgniter

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, angularjs

I am working on an existing site written in CodeIgniter and we are looking at using AngularJS for some pages that require a lot of frontend functionality but we don't want to replace all all CodeIgniter views (at once (yet)).

So i click a link that's controlled by angular's router and it is handled by javascript but next link could be a "normal" request that should handled by the CodeIgniter framework.

Is there some elegant way to combine these two methods? I don't really mind some extra client side overhead because the site is not running in production yet.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking to gradually make less use of CodeIgniter's (CI) routing as your angular application grows. This is not difficult but requires a lot of detail. Which method will work depends on your project structure. *Note: I removed index.php from Code Igniter URLs, so the paths below may be different than default.*

### 1) CodeIgniter installed in root

If CI is installed on the root of your server, you can create a folder within CI (for instance I have an "ng" folder). Your project will look like:

```
    /controllers
    /models
    /ng
    (etc)
    /index.php (code igniter index file)
```

place an .htaccess file within `/ng` with the following:

```
    Order allow, deny
    Allow from all
```

This allows the files within `/ng` to be directly accessed, rather than sending those requests back through CI's routing system. For example you can load this directly now:
`example.com/ng/partials/angular-view.html`

The main web page will still be created by CodeIgniter, but it can now include Angular assets, such as partial views, etc. Eventually you can replace most of what CodeIgniter is doing by just returning a simple page, and having Angular load partial views from `/ng` like it's designed for.

This method is nice because CodeIgniter can control whether that initial page is loaded at all (via some user authentication code in your CI controller). If user isn't logged in, they are redirected and never see the Angular app.

### 2) CodeIgniter in Directory

If CI is installed in a directory, such as `example.com/myapp/(code igniter)` you can simply create a directory next to it, `example.com/myappNg/`

```
    /myapp/
    /myapp/controllers/
    /myapp/models/
    /myapp/(etc)
    /myapp/index.php (code igniter index file)
    /myappNg/
    /myappNg/partials/
    /myappNg/js/
    /myappNg/(etc)
```

Now in your Angular application, you can request resources from CI by making paths relative to the domain root, rather than relative to the Angular app. For instance, in Angular, you will no longer request a partial view from the Angular folder `partials/angular-view.html`, rather you'll want to request views from CI `/myapp/someResource`. Note the leading `/`. "someResource" can return an html document, or JSON or whatever you're doing with Code Igniter in the first place.

Eventually you can replace the number of paths which reference `/myapp/`. Once you no longer use CI for anything, you can simply place your Angular index.html in `/myapp/` and it will continue to reference your paths at `/myappNg/`.

TL;DR Make your Angular app fully available and decouple it from CodeIgniter. Gradually move toward using Angular partial views and other JSON sources instead of linking to CodeIgniter pages. Eventually replace your CodeIgniter endpoint with an HTML file which bootstraps Angular.

Comment: This is the right way to go if you were actually doing this, we ended up creating an codeigniter API and a seperate angularjs frontend.

Comment: How did you manage the sessions in your transittion of Codeigniter to Angular?

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to keep your backend code separate from the angular code
and use the codeInginter code as an API

/Codeigniter Code
/Angular Code

Because CodeIgniter comes with its share of security feature this should be your best bet

Answer (score 1):

I've never used Angular - nevertheless this may help.

> So i click a link that's controlled by angular's router and it is
>   handled by javascript

Does this JavaScript make an Ajax request to one of your CI's controllers? If so, CI now has the `is_ajax_request()` method, which allows you to check if a request (POST or GET) is coming via ajax. You can proceed differently based on a request coming from Ajax vs a normal request.

User guide (*bottom of the page*): http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html

Hope it helps!

Comment: On the server side combining the two techniques there is no problem, but on the client side i'm not really sure how to work with Angulars routing when still having php generated html pages on the site also.

Answer (score 1):

I inherited a CI app and I'm using Angular with CI mainly for routing requests. In my case I am not using Angular templates, so I use a ' '  empty but with a space parameter for the template option in my $routeProvider config. This allows me to do the usual CI ajax requests without too much change to the original server-side code.

```
angular.module('my_app', []).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
   when('/', { template: " ", controller: my_routes.mainpage}). 
   when('/design/:designId/:action', {template: " ", controller: my_routes.show_design}).
   when('/vote_design/:designId', {template: " ", controller: my_routes.vote_design}).
   otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

To addition to the answer given by Aaron Martin, one can also use it as a **client - server approach.**

Lets say we make 2 folders in root of our project :

1. Client
2. Server

**Client** folder will contain all the code of AngularJS and the client side libraries including the Bower and Npm libraries.
The routing of the client side will also be handled by AngularJS router.

There will be factories or services which will act as providers for angularjs on client side.
Those file will contain the code of sending request and receiving response from server side.

**Server** Folder will have the code of Laravel or CodeIgniter or Any other PHP framework.
You will create all the APIs of the requests and develop the functionality accordingly.
Hence the PHP section (Server Directory) at the whole will be storing all the Media Files and Database Files. Moreover it will also have any receiving links for RSS feeds and so on.

The Client shall just receive all the response in JSON or XML format when it requests on any API on its server..

This according to me is one of the finest practice for developing Webapps.

Comment: Client only means a (standard) web application which consumes the web api (rest api). The server is the web (rest) api. Both can be written with CodeIgniter. On client side you might want to use client libraries like AngularJs. There is not more to it.

Answer (score 0):

I picked up a CI site from another programmer I work with that is on leave for a few months. Our site is build mostly with a lot of angular due to the the nature of its purpose. Our solution was a little different.

All that varies from the standard CI framework is a couple folders: `js\angular\controllers` and`js\angular\modules` in CI's application folder, to hold all of the angular model and controller files. Then load the angular docs into the application base folder.