# How to integrate AngularJS (npm, gulp, bower) into CodeIgniter

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter, npm, gulp, bower

I have an AngularJS project located here: https://github.com/M4i4/Frello2

It is a super simple project regarding the content, but it has quite a few things in it: npm, gulp and bower.

My question is:

1. How to insert this project into a CodeIgniter environment (that is a CodeIgniter folder with its application, system, .htaccess and index.php folders/documents).
2. Does it makes sense to do it?
3. I'm running CodeIgniter on XAMPP, but my frello2 AngularJS project is run on a different server: 48080 - How to combine the two?
4. In my frello2 AngularJS project the primary index.html is inside *dist* folder while in CodeIgniter you specify the default view by setting the default controller in the *config* file and then calling *index* function from that controller - So how to combine the two? Which index file will be the primary one?

Comment: Why run a javscript framework with php framework? You could, but it doesn't really make sense unless you are stuck doing that. You're using all the javascript build tools, idk why you'd want to bring php into it.

Comment: Ok, I understand - it does not really make sense. Why do I want to bring php into it? Because of the database. How else am I suppose to connect my existing JS framework with a database? My existing JS framework is just a front-end part of the whole story (has a super small database inside one of the factories). But to build a real project you need to have a database (the back-end part of the whole story).

Comment: Maybe give this a read - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682830/combining-angularjs-and-codeigniter

Comment: This post looks very promising, yes. Haven't tested the solutions described yet, but still.

Comment: Really I think I would say don't mix them unless you really need to, pick one or the other.  But if you're stuck, you're stuck :P. Good luck!

Comment: Or as Han Dijk (your link above) suggest: "...we ended up creating a CodeIgniter API and a seperate AngularJS frontend" But I guess there are better tools to build API with.