# Use angularjs and codeigniter together

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

I am builing an web application using codeigniter with oracle database, I need a suggestion if it is worth to use angularjs with codeigniter, and replace all codeigniter views with angular, will it give better performance?

Comment: yes, it will give better performance. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682830/combining-angularjs-and-codeigniter

Comment: No, it is not worth it